# How to reset the admin user password

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have lost the password for the super user admin account in my Enterprise Integrator deployment.

Is there an option to recover the password? Can I reset it using an API or changing directly in the database?

Need to recover/ reset admin user password.

Comment: Can you please let us know which product you are referring to? And which version of it?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. It is Enterprise Integrator. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can change the admin password by using chpasswd.sh (for linux) or chpasswd.bat (for windows) script. You also need to have the matching JDBC driver depending on the database system you are using.

For detailed steps, please check:

- https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon445/Changing+User+Passwords+in+the+Carbon+Database
- https://medium.com/@kosalasananthana/changing-password-in-wso2-carbon-products-5dd5c808587e

Answer (score 0):

You can find the admin username and the password in the <EI_HOME>/conf/user-mgt.xml under `AdminUser` configs.

```xml
<UserManager>
    <Realm>
        <Configuration>
            <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
            <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
            <AdminUser>
                <UserName>admin</UserName>
                <Password>admin</Password>
            </AdminUser>
            <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
             <!--Enable username claim retrieve from the UM_USER_NAME in JDBC datasources-->
            <OverrideUsernameClaimFromInternalUsername>true</OverrideUsernameClaimFromInternalUsername>
            <Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
        </Configuration>
```

If you have Encrypted values using secure-vaul, you can use the securevault tool to decrypt and get the password. You will be needing the Keystore password for this.